# rutas nuevas en controlador

Tags: laravel-5

Buen dia

He adicionado una metodo nuevo en un controlador resouce, pero no queda como los otros metodos preestablecidos. queda asi.   `panel/registros/tareas`          |                       | `App\Http\Controllers\RegistrosController@tareas`,   me gustaria que quedara registros.tarea pero no se como hacerlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No he entendido muy bien tu pregunta pero si en el archivo `web.php` quieres que aparezca una `URL` a tu modo tendrías que ponerlo de la siguiente manera.

`Route::**action(post or get)**('/registros/tareas','RegistrosController@tareas');`

Intenta dar mas detalles de lo que quieres hacer porque no te entiendo del todo

Comment: Gracias Dohko19